# How to change field length with ArcObject?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, spatial-database, database

I want to change some string field in sdegeodatabse with bellow code. The code are running without any problem. but after running, filed length return to default length. What am i missing?

```
static void writetablecode(IDataset dataset)
        {
            ITable table = dataset as ITable;

            IFieldsEdit fields = table.Fields as IFieldsEdit;
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                IFieldEdit field = fields.Field[i] as IFieldEdit;
                if (field.Type==esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString & field.Length<30 )
                {
                    field.Length_2  = 30;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: did you put your code inside a IWorkspaceEdit editing block? and I think your code must be run under ArcCatalog extention.Anyway,if possible , provide more info about environment and pre-post running code,otherwise alot of things can prevent your code from doing what you want from it.

Comment: Not all data sources support the concept of width change. In fact, very few do. The usual mechanism is to add a new column with the desired width, calclate the values over, delete the old column, and rename the new one.

Comment: Hi, @Reza ,Yes i used Iworckspace edit and its not working yet.

Comment: @Vince , i can to change field length in ArcMap.But in arcobject that change not stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing text fields length needs an exclusive schema lock on the dataset.

> **Exclusive schema locks**—In contrast to shared schema locks, exclusive
>   schema locks are controlled by the developer or ArcGIS application,
>   such as ArcMap or ArcCatalog. An exclusive lock is used to lock a
>   geodatabase dataset or object from use by others to make the necessary
>   changes to it. An exclusive lock is promoted from a shared lock and
>   demoted back to a shared lock when no longer needed. The presence of
>   additional shared schema locks on a dataset or object prevents an
>   exclusive schema lock from being applied and precludes the ability to
>   make changes to the underlying dataset and its schema while it is in
>   use. Only one exclusive schema lock is allowed per dataset. As opposed
>   to shared schema locks, exclusive schema locks are not applied or
>   removed automatically. It is the responsibility of the developer to
>   apply or remove exclusive schema locks.

So, before running your code, make sure to close your dataset in Arcmap or ArcCatalog.

And then this code:

```cs
public void AlterField(IObjectClass objectClass, String fieldName)
{
    // Cast to the ISchemaLock interface.
    ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)objectClass; 
    try
    {
        // Get an exclusive schema lock on the object class. 
        schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
        // Change the text field length here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // An error was raised; therefore, notify the user.
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Since the Finally block is always called, the exclusive lock is demoted
        // to a shared lock after the field is deleted and after an error is raised.
        schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
    }
}
```